# Printing Array in one row in nested xml using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am using xml in VBA which is taking data from an API. I have a nested XMl I am calling but one creates a new array. I can see how to add each nested xml to a cell in excel where they have one value but how would I send the array to cells so that each time an event happened it was added to the next column in the same row?

```
Debug.Print result("month")("day")("events")("elapsed")
```

elapsed is an array which holds a time for each event and there are multiple events per day maybe up to 10

```
 WrkSht.Cells(Count, 1).Value = result("elapsed")
```

would print the first event but I would like the second event to appear in say next column and I cannot find how to code that etc

I am sure this is probably simple but I have searched and cannot see an explanation of how to handle this.

Thanks

Comment: `wrkSheet.Cells(Count, wrkSheets.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(,1).Value = ...` maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
Dim a as Variant, b as Long
Set a = result("elapsed")

For b = 0 to UBound(a)
    WrkSht.Cells(cnt, 1).Offset(,b).Value = a(b)
Next
```

If not, this most likely will:

```
Dim a as Object, b as Object, c as Long
Set a = result("elapsed")

For each b in a
    WrkSht.Cells(cnt, 1).Offset(,c).Value = b
    c = c + 1
Next
```

*Also note that I changed the `Count` variable name to avoid confusion with the native `Count` method.*